# PowerShell Script that Queries SQL Table to CSV File using Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv

I have a basic SQL table of Employees. Using a powershell script I want to export all the employees who have made over 1000 sales to a .csv file and the rest into a different .csv file. I want to accomplish this task by using a loop. I am new to powershell and want to learn the foundations. Can anyone help?

[SQL Table (not real employees)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvTmz.png)

This is what I have so far:

```
$connection.Open()

[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader]$result = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$highDestFile = "C:\high-sales.csv"
$lowDestFile = "C:\low-sales.csv"

while($result.Read()) {
    $ename = $result.GetValue(3);
    $job = $result.GetValue(4);
    $sales = $result.GetValue(7);

    $tableArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $tableArray.Add($ename)      
    $tableArray.Add($job)  
    $tableArray.Add($sales)  

    if($sales -ge 1000) {
        Out-File -FilePath $highDestFile -InputObject $tableArray -Encoding ASCII -Append 
    } else {
        Out-File -FilePath $lowDestFile -InputObject $tableArray -Encoding ASCII -Append 
      }
}

$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from this?

Comment: No errors but it's not filtering the contents in the appropriate columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real familiar with the method you're using to get your results, but I think I have something similar that might be easier to work with for you. It will get all results into PS, and you can filter things from there, rather than getting one result at a time. You obviously know how to make your own SqlConnection and SqlCommand, I'm just including them for future readers to reference.

```
# Define SQL query
$sqlQuery = @"
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
"@

# Create a SqlConnection to connect to the SQL DB
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SqlServer; Database =$SqlCatalog; User Id = $User; Password = $Password"

# Create a SqlCommand object to define the query
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlQuery
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection

# Create a SqlAdapter that actually does the work and manages everything
$sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCmd

# Create an empty DataSet for the query to fill with its results
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

# Execute the query and fill the DataSet (then disconnect)
$sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
$sqlConnection.Close()

# Convert DataSet table to array for ease of use
[Array]$Results = $dataSet.Tables[0]
```

Beyond that you could just use a pair of `Where` statements to filter your results, and output to files.

```
$Results | ?{[int]$_.Sales -ge 1000} | Set-Content $highDestFile
$Results | ?{[int]$_.Sales -lt 1000} | Set-Content $lowDestFile
```